# Why doesn't the GBTC premium get arbitraged away?

Tags: etf, cryptocurrency, arbitrage

My understanding of how [GBTC](https://grayscale.co/bitcoin-trust/) works is that all of the following are true:

1. Accredited investors may provide BTC to Grayscale and receive shares of GBTC in exchange.
2. After a six month lockup, the investor who received these shares may sell them on the open market.
3. GBTC shares are consistently bought and sold at a premium to their corresponding amount of BTC (typically somewhere between 20 and 35%).

It seems a simple arbitrage opportunity is present. The steps are

1. Buy BTC
2. Exchange it for GBTC
3. After 6 months, sell the GBTC and use the proceeds to buy BTC
4. Exchange the BTC for 20-35% more GBTC than you had before.
5. Rinse and repeat

Why does this arbitrage opportunity not cause the premium of GBTC to be reduced to 0?

Furthermore, why doesn't Grayscale sell its own shares on the open market and use the money to purchase BTC or to fund its own operations (potentially reducing the need to charge a 2% annual fee), reducing the premium?

(I know GBTC isn't technically an ETF, but using that tag because it's a close approximate)

Comment: I suspect `After a six month lockup` has a lot to do with it.

Comment: I notice the minimum is $50,000, maybe it's just too chunky?

Comment: It's possible this question is a dupe .. here:  https://money.stackexchange.com/a/127914/41786

Comment: @quid perhaps, but surely a large institutional arbitrageur can afford to wait 6 months for a 30% return.

Comment: @Fattie likewise, the $50k minimum doesn't seem like much of a limitation for institutional investors. It also doesn't explain why Grayscale doesn't perform the arbitrage itself by selling shares on the secondary market until the premium is 0.

Comment: @Daniel, have you seen the volatility in bitcoin? You think a 6 month lockup is reasonable for something that volatile?

Comment: @quid the volatility doesn't matter, though, as long as the value of BTC doesn't fall to 0. The arbitrage works just as well if BTC is worth $250 as it does if it's worth $25000. Maybe the price drops 30% during one or two 6 month windows. But if you do staggered windows over time, the risk of that is limited. Also, note that institutions _are_ buying GBTC and subjecting themselves to the lockout. So it's not like they aren't risking the volatility as it is.

Comment: I disagree that being forced to hold an extremely volatile asset for 6 months for a 30% up side if the price doesn't change is a good idea. I could just buy bitcoin and sell if I feel like it. Or if I don't want to figure out a crypto exchange I can just buy GBTC and sell it when I feel like it.

Comment: @quid that's fine if you disagree with that, but plenty of institutions are doing just that right now. GBTC is by far the biggest holder of Bitcoin currently because institutions _are_ buying into it. My question is if they're doing it anyway, why don't they take advantage of this arbitrage to increase their holdings for free.

Comment: You asked why doesn't a spread get arbitrage away. I would blame the lock up for the spread. You have no idea who holds bitcoin.

Comment: @quid but why should the lock up cause the spread. If I'm ABC Hedge Fund and my lockup ends today, I can sell all my GBTC, buy BTC with the proceeds, and immediately convert it back to GBTC for a 30% profit. If everybody did that, presumably the premium would go to 0. So why don't they do that?

Comment: Because the price can go down more than 30% over the lockup period and you can't stop the bleeding. So what youre calling 30% "profit" could really be a reduced loss if the price of bitcoin fell by half, which it has before. Other assets have other hedging mechanisms, options, futures etc; I'm not sure that BTC futures are even being traded any more; I'm also not sure if there are GBTC options but I suspect there are not.

Comment: @quid I think you've missed the point of my question. Institutional investors _do_ buy GBTC with everything that entails (including the six month lockup). I'm suggesting a way they can have _more_ GBTC at no additional cost; seemingly that's strictly better than not having more. There are also many ways to mitigate the risk of losing everything such as by staggering the investment over six months or shorting BTC.

Comment: Suppose I exchange 1 BTC for GBTC then short sell 1 BTC. Now my risk is hedged entirely.

Comment: hi @quid - i beleve you don't understand what Daniel is saying ... it is actually **priced in** BTC.  BTC is a currency like say Euros or AUD.  Like, nobody cares about the difference in pricing for BTC against USD (or whatever) - as I understand it, what Daniel is describing is a trade *in BTC* .... is that correct Daniel ?

Comment: hence, "Because the price can go down more than 30% over the lockup period and you can't stop the bleeding" - a Bitcoin (satoshi or whatever) is a Thing, like a USD or a Euro.  Many, many, many people hold BTC "as such" ("as a currency"), they don't care if it is changing against USD or EUR or AUD.

Comment: BTW @Daniel I was possibly wrong about the 50k factoid .. I may have been reading the wrong thing.

Comment: @Fattie, sure if your plan was to hodl forever and a collapse of the price of BTC wouldn't bother you then yes this looks like a good arb opportunity, HOWEVER, the pool of people who think this is a good idea is clearly small. Hence the 30% spread.

Comment: @quid Like I said, you could treat this as an arb opportunity in USD as well by shorting BTC at the same time. You'd acquire +1 BTC and convert it to GBTC. Then you'd acquire -1 BTC. Changes in the price of BTC cancel each other out and you're left with just collecting the premium at the end.

Comment: Even if the price of BTC collapses, you still win.

Comment: Not if you no longer want to be in btc. And IF the premium holds by the time you can sell.. I understand the mechanics of the trade, and I'm the one who mentioned the hedges and the lack of typical institutional hedges in this instance. A lockup is a real risk that apparently carries a premium of 30% based on your research.  A LOT can happen in 6 months in crypto, in 6 months GBTC may trade at a discount to holdings. Or, this could be an opportunity, and that unknown is apparently valued at 30% right now.

Comment: @quid perhaps I'm the one who's not understanding what you're saying. What exactly is the risk that you take on with this position? If you can answer that, that's the answer to my question. I've shown that regardless of the direction of the price of BTC (including in the event of a collapse in the price) the arbitrageur would make a profit. You're suggesting that perhaps in six months GBTC will trade at a discount. That's exactly my question! Why has that never happened?! Nor has it come close to happening.

Comment: I'm suggesting a reason why I think GBTC _should_ sometimes trade at a discount, or at least should always trade at close to 0 premium. Yet it doesn't happen. Why?

Comment: @quid .. *"HOWEVER, the pool of people who think this is a good idea is clearly small. Hence the 30% spread"* .. you may be correct, ie it's just that simple: the pool of people in that camp is just small and the result is this fat 30% seeming arbitrage sitting there

Comment: @Fattie Why would the pool of people who think this is a good idea be small? It's arbitrage. Why wouldn't _everybody_ think it's a good idea? That's my entire question.

Comment: @Daniel - ok, I only quoted half of that ongoing conversation.  So, the arbitrage opportunity is in fact for people who "are holding BTC long-term, in and of itself".  (ie they *don't care* about USD/EUR/Etc pricing).   Quid's point was simply that "there may not be that many people like that."  Most arb opportunities are "in" USD; this arb opportunity is "in" BTC.  It does make logical sense that that "pool" is too small for a set of arbitrageurs to emerge.  (I *don't know* if that's the case - just trying to "explore some logical reasons" :/  )

Comment: {Aside - I appreciate you're saying anyone can short-away any USD downside - sure - that's another good logical point. But I'm just thinking through each possibility. The only meaningful suggestion I see so far is:  "simply, there aren't enough 'BTC As Such' players for this arb. market to develop".  That's one possible explanation.

Comment: @Fattie I don't understand what you mean here. This is an arbitrage opportunity in USD. You don't have to be a "BTC As Such" player. At the end of the lockup, you can sell your GBTC for the price of a BTC plus a premium. Use the amount that's the price of a BTC to close your short position and you're left with the premium as free cash.

Comment: @Daniel - I am discussing only the pure arbitrage concept.  (You later added the idea of the short to cover against a currency, like USD or EUR. That really makes sense BUT looking purely at your original question, like you, I see *no reason* this is not arb'd.  So I'm trying to figure out why that is not arb'd. Your original question - just the BTC aspect.)

Comment: actually sorry, not including point1 of your exposition from the question!

Comment: Seems that private placements are closed, so that would also explain a lot of this premium not being subject to arb pressure.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of putting in an answer:

1. Assuming this is a **pure BTC-universe action**.  So this only applies to someone who **has a pile of BTC** and is **keeping it long-term**.  So, you are considering BTC "a currency" - you have no concern with, care about, or involvement with, the ever-changing exchange rates between BTC and AUD, EUR, JPY, USD or whatever.  You have "an account" with a pile of BTC in it. You're BTC all the way down.
2. Assuming the facts as stated (which is all one can do on this site with any question),
3. The mechanism is this: (i) today buy a GBTC. say it cost 100 units (ii) wait six months (iii) sell it and get 130 units
4. Then ... ***yes*** ... as far as I can see, and given point 2, ***it is an arb.***

{Regarding then the question "Why isn't this arbitraged to death?", I simply don't know. The only possible downside (I can see) is total structural collapse of BTC. It could be that the 30%/6 months is (apparently) not enough in most folks minds to cover that risk. [To me that risk seems near-zero, but, that's just me.]} <sup>†</sup>

Hence .. <sup>†</sup>, and noting important Point 2 here, I **would** simply do this today: I cannot see any reason not to.

*To repeat:* I am **answering and only considering this** "in BTC", a pure BTC-universe action.  (Note that it's completely common these days to use / loan / spend / earn "in BTC", with no reference to any national currency, so this is not strange or whacky.) I don't know, care about, nor have thought about this action also involving ordinary currencies. IE, I am completely deleting/ignoring point 1 of points 1-5 from the question. I'm answering this "in BTC only". So, this only applies to (one of the many people/institutions) who have and are keeping a pile of BTC, with no reference to national currency exchange rates regarding BTC.

---

<sup>†</sup> *as an aside, come to think, just as when you put USD in a money market placeholder, it wouldn't matter if there was a total systemic collapse - what would be the difference?!*

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that a 6-month lock up (which I'm assuming exists because of your post) is a bridge too far and is probably enough to justify the 30% premium on its own in this case, it seems there is only a single Authorized Participant:

*This is a snippet from the private placement memorandum for XLM (so the BTC memo may be different):*

> An Authorized Participant must enter into a “Participant Agreement” with the Sponsor and a Trust to govern its placement of orders to create (and, should such Trust commence a redemption program, redeem) Baskets. The
> Participant Agreement sets forth the procedures for the creation and redemption of Baskets and for the delivery of
> digital assets required for creations and redemptions. A copy of the form of Participant Agreement is available for
> inspection at the Sponsor’s principal office identified herein.
>
> Each Authorized Participant must (i) be a registered broker-dealer, (ii) enter into a Participant Agreement with
> the Sponsor and (iii) own an Authorized Participant Self-Administered Account. A list of the current Authorized
> Participants for each Trust can be obtained from the Sponsor. As of the date of this Private Placement Memorandum, **Genesis is the only acting Authorized Participant for the Trusts**. The Sponsor intends to engage additional Authorized Participants that are unaffiliated with the Trusts in the future.
>
> No Authorized Participant has any obligation or responsibility to the Sponsor or any of the Trusts to effect any
> sale or resale of Shares.

Separately, redemptions and private placements to the fund are closed.

[From the Grayscale site](https://grayscale.co/bitcoin-trust/)

> - Grayscale Bitcoin Trust does not currently operate a redemption program and may halt creations from time to time. There can be no assurance that the value of the shares will approximate the value of the Bitcoin held by the Trust and the shares may trade at a substantial premium over or discount to the value of the Trust's Bitcoin. The Trust may, but will not be required to, seek regulatory approval to operate a redemption program.

And from the [Private Placement section of the Grayscale Site](https://grayscale.co/startinvesting/):

[image]

So there are a few contributing factors that can explain why this spread isn't being arbed away.  Leaving aside the 6-month lockup and living in the fantasy world of indifference to dollar fluctuations, the pool of people who could arb this away is extremely small, one.  So you *can't* exploit this opportunity, if you think that's what this is.

Comment: Grayscale's [investors page](https://grayscale.co/investors/) says that accredited investors are eligible to participate in private placement offerings. I'm not sure how exactly to square that with the thing your said about there being only one authorized participant. Could you link where you found that? As for placement being closed, Grayscale regularly opens and closes private placement for _new_ investors (new investments were only just put on hold about a week ago and nobody expects it to be for very long); however, AFAIK it generally remains open for existing investors.

Comment: I clicked through the private placement area (which is what that screenshot shows) and opened the Private Placement Memorandum [PPM] doc for XLM; then quoted the whole Authorized Participants section here.  The language is the same in the XLM, ZEC and ZEN PPM docs (which are the only ones where private placement is available).